# Cannot make sense of timestamptz offset

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Sample code:

```
show timezone;
   TimeZone    
---------------
 Europe/Berlin
(1 row)

create table foo (ts timestamp without time zone);
insert into foo values ('2023-10-28 23:58:00');
insert into foo values ('2023-10-29 00:58:00');
insert into foo values ('2023-10-29 01:58:00');

select (ts at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Europe/Berlin')::timestamptz as x from foo order by x;
           x            
------------------------
 2023-10-29 01:58:00+02
 2023-10-29 02:58:00+01   <<<<------
 2023-10-29 02:58:00+01
(3 rows)
```

Should the marked line not be

```
 2023-10-29 02:58:00+02
```

?

My understanding is that the clock ticks backwards at 3AM in Europe/Berlin, so `UTC '2023-10-29 00:58:00'` should correspond to `02:58:00` *before* the clock goes back, hence still +02,or CEST if you prefer. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `at time zone 'Europe/Berlin'` causes the offset to be lost.  (Run that query and see).  Then when you cast back to timestamptz, it has no info on which to pick the offset to re-add.  There is no way to see though to the beginning to remember what offset it originally had.

```
select 
   (ts at time zone 'utc') as x1,
   (ts at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Europe/Berlin') as x2,
   (ts at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Europe/Berlin')::timestamptz as x3,
from foo order by x;
```

Comment: Right, so in fact being the postgres time zone already `Europe/Berlin`, I can just do `select (ts at time zone 'utc')::timestamptz` and let postgres do the translation, which results in the expected offset. Thanks.